# Permission denied with full permissions

Tags: command-line, permissions

I was recently working on a project and I came across a problem that I cannot figure out. Lets say that you have a directory called `dir1`. Inside of this directory, you have two subdirectories called `sub1` and `sub2`. There is a file in `sub1` (we can call this `file1`) that you would like to copy to `sub2`. You are the owner and have full permissions on the directory, subdirectory, and file. You try to copy the file like so:

```
cp -p dir1/sub1/file1 dir1/sub2
```

The resuilting error is that permission is denied. You try multiple workarounds (saving it to the desktop works fine but copying it from there into `sub2` won't work either, using the Windows File Explorer GUI gives a permissions error as well) but are still not successful. Then you try this:

```
cp -p dir1/sub1/file1 dir1
mv dir1/file1 dir1/sub2
```

and this successfully transfers the file into `sub2`. My question is, why wasn't I able to copy the file directly to `sub2`? It's worth mentioning that I had moved many other files from `sub1` to `sub2` using the same command listed, but the files that gave this permission error (this happened twice) were both windows .exe files.

Comment: “It’s worth mentioning that I had moved many other files from `sub1` to `sub2` using the same command listed …”  Yes, it certainly is — so much so that you should have mentioned it earlier than *the last sentence in the question!*  Does this problem occur for all `.EXE` files in `sub1`, or just a few enigmatic exceptions?  Can you reproduce this problem (if you create a new `dir1`, `sub1`, and `sub2`)?  Are the `.EXE` files actively running when you do this?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  What is your software configuration?  You mention the “Windows File Explorer GUI,” so I guess you’re running Cygwin (or something similar) under Windows.  What versions?  Please answer these questions (and provide any other information that might be relevant).  Also, post the output of `ls -laR` from `dir1`, and the permissions of all the relevant files and directories as determined by Windows Explorer.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.